# python 2.7 divide list produced from counter into separate columns in csv

Tags: python, csv, collections, counter

I have two columns of data from a csv file that I've counted (basically the number of tags per chapter in a novel). I now need to separate this data into three columns: tag, chapter number, and count. Here's what I have so far:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as z:
reader = csv.reader(z)
for row in reader:
    labels.append(row[0])
    chapLabels.append(int(row[1]))
    combo = zip(labels, chapLabels)
    c = collections.Counter(combo) 
    d = c.items()

    with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerows(d)
```

This outputs two columns, the first is a list of my counts that includes a string and an integer in this format: ("tag1", 37); the second is the chapter number. I'm still a beginner but have searched widely for an answer to this question and have come up short.

A bit more clarification about input / output:

My original CSV file has 2 columns of tags and their chapter locations:

- tag1, 32
- tag1, 17
- tag1, 17
- tag2, 5
- tag3, 32

My code counts how many times a tag appears in each chapter and then creates a list like this: (('tag1', 32): 1, ('tag1', 17): 2, ('tag2', 5): 1, ('tag3', 32): 1)

I've then tried to break that up into 3 columns of a CSV file that include tag, count, and chapter location. Instead, the current output of my code is 2 columns:

- ('tag1', 32), 1
- ('tag1', 17), 2
- ('tag2', 5), 1
- ('tag3', 32), 1

I want it to be:

- tag1, 32, 1
- tag1, 17, 2
- tag2, 5, 1
- tag3, 32, 1

Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: what does your dict look like? Items is going to have key/value pairings so I don't see where the third column is going to come from

Comment: You are also continually overwriting `output.csv` in your loop so you ar only every going to see the last c.items(). Without seeing some input and what you want as output your question is pretty vague